# Highcharts - Bar Graph stacking - with date / time line

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I'm working with some bar graph where I have problems adding a date/time line in the bottom of the graph.

What I want is:

[image]

I'm able to create the bar graph but I can't make the date/time to work..

Any suggestions on how I can do it?

I will normally show 24 hours in the bar graph

I have looked the functions below but could not make it work..

- pointStart
- pointInterval
- type: 'datetime' (yAxis)

[This is what I have now (JsFiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/8qzbf5mj/7/)

My Javascript Code:

```
    $(function () {
    Highcharts.setOptions({
        global: {
            useUTC: true
        }
    });
    $('#chart1').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'bar',
            animation: false
        },
        credits: { enabled: false },
        exporting: { enabled: false },
        title: {
            text: null
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: [ '' ]
        },
        yAxis: {
            min: 0,
            ceiling: 86400, // one day (3600*24)
            title: {text: null }

        },
        legend: {
            enabled: false,
            reversed: true
        },
        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                stacking: 'normal',
                animation: false
            },
            bar: {
                animation: false,
                borderWidth:0
            }
        },
        series: [
                { name: 'TODO'
                , color: 'Yellow' 
                , data: [ 7200 ] }, // Two hours
                { name: 'TODO'
                , color: 'Red'
                , data: [ 7200 ] },
                { name: 'TODO'
                , color: 'Red'
                , data: [ 7200 ] },
                { name: 'TODO'
                , color: 'Red'
                , data: [ 7200 ] },
                { name: 'TODO'
                , color: 'Red'
                , data: [ 7200 ] },
                { name: 'TODO'
                , color: 'Yellow'
                , data: [ 7200 ] },
                { name: 'TODO'
                , color: 'Red'
                , data: [ 7200 ] },                
                { name: 'TODO'
                , color: 'Red'
                , data: [ 7200 ] },
                { name: 'TODO'
                , color: 'Red'
                , data: [ 7200 ] },
                { name: 'TODO'
                , color: 'Yellow'
                , data: [ 7200 ] },    
                { name: 'TODO'
                , color: 'Red'
                , data: [ 7200 ] },  
                { name: 'TODO'
                , color: 'Red'
                , data: [ 7200 ] },                  
        ]
    });
});
```

HTML Code

```
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<div id="chart1" style="width: 100%; height: 250px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

Comment: Refer this http://jsfiddle.net/FxD58/1/

Comment: Your timestamps should be multiplied by 1000 (javascript timestamps). PointInterval / pointStart don't work, because on yAxis (in bar charts xAxis = yAxis) you define values, which are printed. So these paramters no make sense.